# rest_api_init does not fire

Tags: wordpress, webhooks

I have a plugin that works on one server but not on the other.

I have defined a webhook with

```
`//  Create webhook
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    error_log("rest_api_init: register route" );
    $result = register_rest_route( 'zuzz-club/v1', '/gc/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    //         register_rest_route( 'zuzz-club/v1', '/gc', array(
        'methods' => [ 'POST', 'GET' ],
        'callback' => 'zuzz_gc_webhook',
        'args' => array(),
        'permission_callback' => function () {
                return true;
            }
    ) );
    if ($result) {
        error_log("rest_api_init: route registered successfully" );
    } else {
        error_log("rest_api_init: route failed to register" );
    }
} );

function zuzz_gc_webhook($request) {
    error_log("zuzz_gc_webhook: request ".print_r($request, true));
.....
`
```

But it does not fire when tested. I have added

`

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'zuzz_parse_gocardless_request', 1);

function zuzz_parse_gocardless_request() {
    error_log("zuzz_parse_gocardless_request: SERVER ".print_r($_SERVER, true));
......
`  
This does fire, and reports that 
[REQUEST_URI] => /zuzz-club/v1/gc/1
[CONTENT_TYPE] => application/json
[REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
```

`

Comment: DId you check this ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516056/wordpress-rest-api-add-action-rest-api-init-callback-does-not-call-the-cal

Comment: Yes, I am using Post name permalinks